Pitru Paksha Ritual
Pitru Paksha
Veneration of the dead
Crow
We offer food to the Crow Bird between the 16 day period.
The crow is considered as a soul or spirit of our ancestors.
Is it because of the Crow's intelligence?
Crows are omnivores.
Why not any other bird or animal other than Crow? Why not Cats or Dogs? Is it because they are carnivores?
